# How to sort a list of timings like this [ 2:00 AM , 10:00 AM , 6:00 PM ] in dart-flutter?

Tags: algorithm, flutter, sorting, dart

I'm working on a flutter app, one of its features is to add your drug dose timings to get a reminder to take your drug. and I need to sort the timings to get the 'next_dose' to appear here :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j5KrRbDj0J28_FrMKy7dazk4m9dw202d/view?usp=sharing

**this is an example of the list which I want to sort**

```
[8:30 AM, 3:30 PM, 9:30 AM, 7:00 AM]
```

**function I made to get the greater between 2 timings**

```
int greater(String element,String element2){
      var hour = element.toString().split(':')[0];
      var hour2 = element2.toString().split(':')[0];
      var minute = element.toString().split(':')[1].split(' ')[0];
      var minute2 = element2.toString().split(':')[1].split(' ')[0];
      var day = element.toString().split(':')[1].split(' ')[1];
      var day2 = element2.toString().split(':')[1].split(' ')[1];
      if(day == 'AM' && day2 == 'PM')
        return -1;
      else if(day2 == 'AM' && day == 'PM')
        return 1;
      else if(day == day2)
      {
        if(int.parse(hour) > int.parse(hour2)) return -1;
        else if(int.parse(hour) < int.parse(hour2)) return 1;
        else{
          if(int.parse(minute) > int.parse(minute2))
            return 1;
          else
            return -1;
        }
      }
```

**here I tried to use the function to sort the list'Dose'**

```
dose.sort((a,b)=>greater(a,b));
```

Comment: It would be much simpler to parse your times to an integer (e.g. `'3:30 PM'` => `1530`), (or to a `DateTime` object) and then sorting should be trivial.

Comment: the list items are string type I tried to parse but I didn't success

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of creating a `sort` callback with a lot of complicated logic, it'd be simpler if the callback parsed the time strings either into an `int` or into a `DateTime` object and compared those.  For example:

```dart
/// Parses a time of the form 'hh:mm AM' or 'hh:mm PM' to a 24-hour
/// time represented as an int.
///
/// For example, parses '3:30 PM' as 1530.
int parseTime(String time) {
  var components = time.split(RegExp('[: ]'));
  if (components.length != 3) {
    throw FormatException('Time not in the expected format: $time');
  }
  var hours = int.parse(components[0]);
  var minutes = int.parse(components[1]);
  var period = components[2].toUpperCase();
  
  if (hours < 1 || hours > 12 || minutes < 0 || minutes > 59) {
    throw FormatException('Time not in the expected format: $time');
  }
  
  if (hours == 12) {
    hours = 0;
  }
  
  if (period == 'PM') {
    hours += 12;
  }
  
  return hours * 100 + minutes;
}

void main() {
  var list = ['8:30 AM', '3:30 PM', '9:30 AM', '7:00 AM'];
  list.sort((a, b) => parseTime(a).compareTo(parseTime(b)));
  print(list); // Prints: [7:00 AM, 8:30 AM, 9:30 AM, 3:30 PM]
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `package:intl` and [`DateFormat.parse`](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat/parse.html) to easily parse strings into `DateTime` objects.

Answer (score 1):

Here we get the time slot by passing the start and end time duration.

```
List<String> createTimeSlot(
    Duration startTime, Duration endTime, BuildContext context,
    {Duration step = const Duration(minutes: 30)} // Gap between interval
    ) {
  var timeSlot = <String>[];

  var hourStartTime = startTime.inHours;
  var minuteStartTime = startTime.inMinutes.remainder(60);

  var hourEndTime = endTime.inHours;
  var minuteEndTime = endTime.inMinutes.remainder(60);

  do {
    timeSlot.add(TimeOfDay(hour: hourStartTime, minute: minuteStartTime)
        .format(context));
    minuteStartTime += step.inMinutes;
    while (minuteStartTime >= 60) {
      minuteStartTime -= 60;
      hourStartTime++;
    }
  } while (hourStartTime < hourEndTime ||
      (hourStartTime == hourEndTime && minuteStartTime <= minuteEndTime));

  debugPrint("Number of slot $timeSlot");

  return timeSlot;
}
```

Function call

```
createTimeSlot(Duration(hours: 1, minutes: 30),
        Duration(hours: 3, minutes: 30), context);
```

Output:

```
Number of slot [1:30 AM, 2:00 AM, 2:30 AM, 3:00 AM, 3:30 AM]
```