# Compare Hours in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm facing troubles trying to compare times in flutter.
I'm receiving a time : 09:30
I want to compare it with the current time and run some action.

Eg: received time from api (string) 09:30
current date : 2021-11-30 14:57:23

I want to compare 09:30 and 14:57
If 09:30 < 14:57 run some action

Thanks

Comment: You will need to parse the `String` to extract the hour and minute, then construct a `DateTime` with that time and the current date, and then compare them using typical `DateTime` comparison methods.  There are many other questions like this (for example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68172468/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this comparator function for that:

```dart
int compareHours(DateTime a, DateTime b) {
  var result = a.hour.compareTo(b.hour);
  if(result != 0) {
    return result;
  }
  
  result = a.minute.compareTo(b.minute);
  if(result != 0) {
    return result;
  }

  return a.second.compareTo(b.second);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the methods from `DateTime` class:

`isAfter()`, `isBefore()` and `isAtSameMomentAs()`